# Flash debug player won't launch

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe

I'm having major issues with my Flash Debug Player. For a while now it hasn't been able to launch properly, or at least so it seems. Whenever I visit a site with the debug player enabled I just get the sad puzzle piece and a message saying that Macromedia Flash Player has crashed. It's the same thing with ADL, I can only run it with the -nodebug flag.

It works just fine if I install the regular Flash Player or use the one built into Chrome.

If I'm not mistaken, this might have begun to happen when I installed the Flashbug debugger in Firefox.

I've done the following:

- tried installing an older version of the debug player
- uninstalled flash and AIR completely before installing a new version
- made sure there is a flashlog.txt file

I've edited my mm.cfg to look like this:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

Nothing is written to flashlog.txt when I try using the debug player, or ADL, and it works with the regular player and ADL with -nodbug enabled, so I'm guessing something happens with the logging part of the player. When running ADL i get "Bus error: 10" in the terminal.

Could anyone give me a hint, or any ideas at all on how to fix this? Could there be some hidden configuration file somewhere that isn't removed when I uninstall to do a fresh install or something?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you tell me what version you are running. The error appears when you try to debug a project from Flex or Flash Builder? I Had similar when trying to debug projects in Flash Builder with Firefox, the solution (for me) was to uninstall flash player with this [program](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html) and then install again a correct version, in this case try with the version 9 or 10. 
I hope it will be helpful

Comment: As stated in the question - I've tried installing multiple versions after uninstalling. The version I'd like to get running is the latest, 11.4, on Mac. Thanks, though.